# SCSF vs Acropolis

Tags: scsf, acropolis

What's the different between SCSF and Acropolis ?

Answer (score 2):

SCSF (Smart client Software Factory) is a set of tools (using the Guidance Automation Extensions to Visual Studio) for building apps using the Composite UI Application Block.

The Composite UI Application Block is an application framework that is based on the Composite UI pattern, basically providing plumbing for loosely-coupled UIs.  It was heavily based upon the "ObjectBuilder" Dependency Injection container that was developed inside Microsoft patterns & practices.

If I recall correctly, Acropolis was going to be a "reboot" of the Composite UI Application Block.  [It is no longer being worked on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_codename_Acropolis), but (according, at least, to Wikipedia) some of its concepts are incorporated into current Microsoft products like Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_codename_Acropolis

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480482.aspx

Acropolis has not been released yet. SCSF is available now? Not sure what else you could find out since one of them technically is not in existence :)

Comment: SCSF is available at least since 2008.